# nodejs get undefined getting collection on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

thanks for helping me.
I am unable to return documents from my Orders collection.
I did exactly the same on another project and it worked...
Could someone help me understand why it's returning undefined?

MONGOBD
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fty6M.png)

## **server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const routes = require('./routes');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Conectado no banco");
    app.emit('pronto');
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(`Erro: ${e}`));
```

## **pedidosModels.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const client = new mongoClient(process.env.DB_URI, );

async function buscaPedidos() {

  try {
    const db = client.db('hamburgueria');
    console.log("Estou em BUSCAR PEDIDOS")
    const result = await db.collection('Pedidos').find({}).sort({
      senha: -1
    }).limit(5).toArray(function (err, results) {
      console.log(`results ${results}`);
      console.log(`PEDIDOS: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
    });;


  } finally {
    client.close();
  }

};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG5h9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved...
I changed the versions:

```
      "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
```

And I move the console.log() for another line:

```
async function buscaPedidos() {

  try {
    const db = client.db('hamburgueria');
    console.log("Estou em BUSCAR PEDIDOS")
    const result = await db.collection('Pedidos').find({}).sort({
      senha: -1
    }).limit(5).toArray()
    const pedidos = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(`PEDIDOS: ${JSON.stringify(pedidos)}`)
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }

};
```